# Proving that a function is depend upon a specific variable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, rational-functions

Suppose that $f_1(x,z),f_2(y)$, $g_1(x,y),g_2(z)$ are non-constant *rational* functions and let
$$
F(x,y,z)=\big[\overbrace{f_1(x,z)+f_2(y)}^{f}\big]\big[\overbrace{g_1(x,y)+g_2(z)}^{g}\big].
$$
I want to prove that $F$ must depend upon $x$, that is, that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\not\equiv0$.

Comment: By $f_1(x,z)$ we mean that $f_1$ is depend upon both $x$ and $z$. The same for $g_1(x,y)$, $f_2(y)$ and $g_2(z)$.

**My attempt**: Suppose otherwise that $F(x,y)=\phi(y,z)$, where $\phi$ is some rational function. Note that
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=
f\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}+g\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\equiv0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial x\partial y}=
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}+
f\frac{\partial^2 g_1}{\partial x\partial y}+
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}
\equiv0
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^3F}{\partial x\partial y\partial z}=
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}\frac{\partial^2g_1}{\partial x\partial y}+
\frac{\partial^2f_1}{\partial x\partial z}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}
\equiv0.
$$
Observe that the last equality is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}\cdot
\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}
\right]\equiv0.
$$
Therefore $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}\cdot
\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}$ does not depend upon $x$. How to continue from here?

Comment: What if $\ f_1(x,z)\equiv z\ $ and $\ g_1(x,y)\equiv y\ $

Comment: By $f_1(x,z)$ I mean that $f_1$ is depend upon both $x$ and $z$. Same for $g_1(x,y)$. I will Edit to clarify that. Thanks!

Comment: You also need $\ f_2\not\equiv0\ $ and $\ g_2\not\equiv0\ $. Otherwise $\ f_1(x,z)=xz\ $ and $\ g_1(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}\ $ would give you $\ F\ $ independent of $\ x\ $.

Comment: Of course, but in the question I wrote *non-constant* rational functions, so it cover that.